# How to add wx.Treectrl items to another wx. treectrl

Tags: python, python-2.7, wxpython

I have two Treectrl boxes and able to see the text files inside a folder in treectrl1. Need to select and  Add items[text files] from one TreeCtrl to another Treectrl box on click of a Butoon[Add]. Please help me with the code as i am new to Wx python. Thanks in advance.

```
def onclick(self, event):
     item = self.testtree.GetSelections()
     print self.testtree.GetPyData(item)
```

Using above line of code was trying to access the selected item to move to the another treectrl . But was unable to retrieve item, instead it was printing the id of the selected item

Comment: post the code you've tried

Comment: Edited my code. Please help

Answer (score 0):

Without being able to see your code, I'll have to guess.

```
item = self.testtree.GetSelections()
```

returns a `list` of currently selected items not a single instance.
Note: `GetSelections` can only be used if the `style` of the `TreeCtrl` is `wx.TR_MULTIPLE`

```
item = self.testtree.GetSelection()
```

on the other hand does return a single item.

I suspect that you need something like:

```
items = self.tree.GetSelections()
for item in items:
    print(self.tree.GetItemText(item))
```